# Am I allowed to post a link to the website of my company?

Tags: discussion

In [this thread](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/is-there-any-source-of-unlimited-exercises-and-problems#comment51209_18662), the original poster asked if there were any resources that went from kindergarten up to calculus-level math... I am kinda developing something like that, but only for number sense and introductory algebra. I wanted to ask if I'm allowed to post a link to my company website, a small portion of which might exemplify what he's looking for.

Am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for asking upfront, many (especially new) users just do it anyway and might then be confronted by the [Stack Exchange rules for self-promotion](/help/promotion). The gist of those is in the first paragraph:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

If you, as a long-standing contributor, mention your own product in one place where it definitely helps answering the question, that's well within the guidelines (as long as you explicitly state it's your own product). Also (but that's true for all links) it should be a kind of 'reference' or 'read more'; the essential information should always be in the answer itself.

> **Don't include links except to *support* what you've written.** Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer. See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)